# Image to base64 in react native

Tags: react-native

How to convert local image into base64 in react native and upload on server, please help anyone to solve this query. I already tried using library which available on google named **image-to-base64** npm.

Answer (score 2):

With expo API

```
import { ImageManipulator } from 'expo';

const response = await ImageManipulator.manipulateAsync("file to local path", [], { base64: true })
console.log('base64res' + JSON.stringify(response));
```

Answer (score 1):

All guys we can get an base64 string of the image using Image picker in react native for Profile uses and many more.
Here I put the piece of code which will help to get base64 string in react native using image picker function.

```
    selectPhotoTapped() {
const options = {
  quality: 1.0,
  maxWidth: 500,
  maxHeight: 500,
  storageOptions: {
    skipBackup: true,
  },
};

ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, response => {
  console.log('Response = ', response.data);

  if (response.didCancel) {
    console.log('User cancelled photo picker');
  } else if (response.error) {
    console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
  } else if (response.customButton) {
    console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
  } else {
    // let source = { uri: response.uri };  <-- here you can get uri of image
    //  var RNFS = require('react-native-fs');
    // You can also display the image using data:
    let source =  'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+ [response.data];  //<-- here you can get image with base64string

    this.setState({
      avatarSource: source,
    });

    // this.setState({
    //   Profile_Picture:this.state.avatarSource
    // })
    // console.log(this.state.Profile_Picture)


  }
});
```

}

After that you can using onPress event take image from your library but before that you have to grant permission for use android or IOS image from local storage.
link of the installation for image picker 
[Use This Link for Installation of Image picker in react native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-imagepicker)

Answer (score 0):

Using [react-native-image-base64](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-base64):

```
import ImgToBase64 from 'react-native-image-base64';

ImgToBase64.getBase64String('file://path/to/file')
  .then(base64String => {
       // Send the base64String to server
   })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Sir can you send me an example??

Comment: Thanks so much sir but i got it by another way.

Answer (score 0):

only solution is react-native-fs

```
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

RNFS.readFile(this.state.imagePath, 'base64')
.then(res =>{
  console.log(res);
});
```